# Multiclipboard exercise chapter 9 Automate the boring Stuff python

Tags: python

i have a code:

```
import shelve, pyperclip, sys

#open the shelve
mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')

#save clipboard content
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
#either copy keys to clipboard or copy value of a key
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
        print("123")
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbShelf:
       pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])

#close out the shelve
mcbShelf.close()
```

I understand the code(whole code is from book example) but it doesent work... In exercise it was a task to create a bat file:
ex from book: @pyw.exe C:\Python35\mcb.pyw %*

so i did:
@pyw.exe D:\PythonProjekt\AutomateBook\r9\mcb.pyw %* and save it as mcb.bat, i put this file into a C:\Users\Dominik

and when i try to open this script by using cmd, for example: mcb list, nothing happens, no error but did nothing, also the same when i try: mcb save sth
i think problem is in bat file but what is wrong?

Comment: per PEP 8 (and I suggest that You follow it) importing modules should be split in lines and NOT like this: `import module1, module2` (unless You are importing objects `from` a  module)

Comment: did You navigate to the directory and then run the bat file?

Comment: spliting imported modules  nothing changes. Navigated what? cmd when running mcb? i think yes bcs mcb.bat is in my home directory and i have no error 'no such file' while running

Comment: about splitting imports: it is a suggestion, won't solve the problem but the code's formatting will be in compliance with PEP 8. also did You just rename this `.py` type file to `.bat`? like it is a bat file with ONLY python code? if so it won't work because bat expects welll cmd? code

Comment: i dont understand what .py? what i should change?